# How to make my tkinter prototype system calculate the correct total price

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

I am a beginner, I am creating a prototype system for a DIY Store as part of my assignment, with Tkinter. The application works by filling out a simple survey to create an order.  At the bottom of the page after you click that button 'Enter Data', your result of selections should appear including your total price.

I need some advice on how to write the calculation part of my system, which starts from `def total():` within the code but the calculation part comes at `total_length`, which is where I am getting an error for 'not defining it' [the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2je37.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5lZg.png).

I don't know how to get passed that. I thought it was defined by my calculation of `total_length = wallpaper_length_cost * 0.5`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk

def display_wallpaper_prints():
    window = tk.Toplevel()
    window.title("View Wallpaper prints")
    window.geometry("400x400")
    image_path = "Picture1A.png"
    img = tk.PhotoImage(file=image_path)
    label = ttk.Label(window, image=img)
    label.image = img
    label.pack(side="top", pady=10)


def enter_data():


    full_name = "Name: " + first_name_field.get() + "  " + surname_field.get()
    name_label.config(text=full_name)
    name_label.grid(column=0, row=4, columnspan=2)
    employeeID = "Employee ID: " + employeeID_field.get()
    ID_label.config(text=employeeID)
    ID_label.grid(column=6, row=4, columnspan=2)
    wallpaper_length = "Wallpaper length: " + wallpaper_length_combobox.get()
    wl_label.config(text=wallpaper_length)
    wl_label.grid(column=0, row=5, columnspan=2)
    wallpaper_selection = "Wallpaper selection: " + wallpaper_selection_combobox.get()
    ws_label.config(text=wallpaper_selection)
    ws_label.grid(column=6, row=5, columnspan=2)
    wallpaper_paste = "Wallpaper paste: " + wallpaper_paste_selection_combobox.get()
    wp_label.config(text=wallpaper_paste)
    wp_label.grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=2)
    extras = "Extras: " + extras_selection_combobox.get()
    extras_label.config(text=extras)
    extras_label.grid(column=6, row=6, columnspan=2)
    lining_paper = "Lining: " + lining_paper_selection_combobox.get()
    lining_paper_label.config(text=lining_paper)
    lining_paper_label.grid(column=0, row=7, columnspan=2)

    print(full_name, employeeID)
    print(wallpaper_length, wallpaper_selection)
    print(extras, wallpaper_paste, lining_paper)


def total_cost():

    wallpaper_per_metre_cost = 0
    if wallpaper_selection_combobox.get() == "Option A (30p per metre)":
        wallpaper_per_metre_cost = 0.30
    elif wallpaper_selection_combobox.get() == "Option B (60p per metre)":
        wallpaper_per_metre_cost = 0.60


    wallpaper_length_cost = 0
    if wallpaper_length_combobox.get() == "10 metres":
        wallpaper_length_cost = 10
    elif wallpaper_length_combobox.get() == "15 metres":
        wallpaper_length_cost = 15
    elif wallpaper_length_combobox.get() == "20 metres":
        wallpaper_length_cost = 20
    elif wallpaper_length_combobox.get() == "25 metres":
        wallpaper_length_cost = 25

    extras_per_metre_cost = 0
    if extras_selection_combobox == "Foil (12p per metre)":
        extras_per_metre_cost = 0.12
    elif extras_selection_combobox == "Glitter (18p per metre)":
        extras_per_metre_cost = 0.18
    elif extras_selection_combobox == "Embossing (6p per metre)":
        extras_per_metre_cost = 0.06

    lining_paper_cost = 0
    if lining_paper_selection_combobox == "Yes, £7.63 per roll":
        lining_paper_cost = 7.63
    elif lining_paper_selection_combobox == "No":
        lining_paper_cost = 0

    wallpaper_paste_cost = 0
    if wallpaper_paste_selection_combobox == "Yes, £13.99 per tub":
        wallpaper_paste_cost = 13.99
    elif wallpaper_paste_selection_combobox == "No":
        wallpaper_paste_cost = 0

    total_length = wallpaper_length_cost.get() * 0.5

    wallpaper_total = wallpaper_per_metre_cost * total_length
    extras_total = extras_per_metre_cost * wallpaper_length_cost
    total_cost = wallpaper_total + extras_total + wallpaper_paste_cost + lining_paper_cost
    total_price = "Total price: £" + total_cost.get()
    total_price_label.config(text=total_price)
    total_price_label.grid(column=0, row=10, columnspan=2)

    print(total_length)
    print(wallpaper_total)
    print(extras_total)
    print(total_price)




window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Wallpapering with Sally")

frame = tk.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

#Customer info details
customer_info_frame = tk.LabelFrame(frame, text="Customer details")
customer_info_frame.grid(row= 0, column= 0, padx= 30, pady= 30)

first_name_label = tk.Label(customer_info_frame, text= "First Name")
first_name_label.grid(row= 0, column= 0)
surname_label = tk.Label(customer_info_frame, text= "Surname")
surname_label.grid(row= 0, column= 2)

first_name_field = tk.Entry(customer_info_frame)
surname_field = tk.Entry(customer_info_frame)
first_name_field.grid(row= 0, column= 1)
surname_field.grid(row= 0, column= 3)

employeeID_label = tk.Label(customer_info_frame, text= "Employee ID")
employeeID_label.grid(row= 1, column= 0)
employeeID_field = tk.Entry(customer_info_frame)
employeeID_field.grid(row= 1, column= 1)

for widget in customer_info_frame.winfo_children():
    widget.grid_configure(padx=30, pady= 30)

#Wallpaper form
wallpaper_frame = tk.LabelFrame(frame)
wallpaper_frame.grid(row=2, column=0)

#Wallpaper Legnth
wallpaper_length_label = tk.Label(wallpaper_frame, text= "How many metres of wallpaper would you like?")
wallpaper_length_combobox = ttk.Combobox(wallpaper_frame, values=["10 metres","15 metres","20 metres","25 metres"])
wallpaper_length_label.grid (row= 1, column= 0, pady= 10)
wallpaper_length_combobox.grid (row= 2, column= 0)


#Wallpaper Selection
wallpaper_selection_label = tk.Label(wallpaper_frame, text= "Which wallpaper would you like?")
wallpaper_selection_combobox = ttk.Combobox(wallpaper_frame, values=["Option A (30p per metre)","Option B (60p per metre)"])
wallpaper_selection_label.grid(row= 3, column= 0, sticky= "news", padx= 15, pady= 10)
wallpaper_selection_combobox.grid(row= 4, column= 0)

#Select Extras
extras_selection = tk.Label(wallpaper_frame, text= "Would you like any of the extras below?")
extras_selection_combobox = ttk.Combobox(wallpaper_frame, values= ["Foil (12p per metre)", "Glitter (18p per metre)", "Embossing (6p per metre)"])
extras_selection.grid(row= 5, column= 0, sticky= "news", padx= 15, pady= 10)
extras_selection_combobox.grid(row= 6, column= 0)


#lining paper combobox
lining_paper_selection = tk.Label(wallpaper_frame, text= "Do you require Lining paper? (20m rolls for £7.63)")
lining_paper_selection_combobox = ttk.Combobox(wallpaper_frame, values=["Yes, £7.63 per roll", "No"])
lining_paper_selection.grid(row= 7, column= 0, sticky= "news", padx= 15, pady= 10)
lining_paper_selection_combobox.grid(row= 8, column= 0)

#wallpaper paste selection
wallpaper_paste_selection = tk.Label(wallpaper_frame, text= "Do you require wallpaper paste? (10kg ready-mixed tubs)")
wallpaper_paste_selection_combobox = ttk.Combobox(wallpaper_frame, values=["Yes, £13.99 per tub", "No"])
wallpaper_paste_selection.grid(row= 9, column= 0, pady= 10, padx= 10)
wallpaper_paste_selection_combobox.grid (row=10, column= 0)

#enter data button
enter_data_button = ttk.Button(frame, text= "Enter Data", command= enter_data)
enter_data_button.grid(row= 3, column= 0, sticky= "news", padx= 20, pady= 20)

#wallpaper_prints_button
wallpaper_prints_button = ttk.Button(wallpaper_frame, text= "View wallpaper prints", command= display_wallpaper_prints)
wallpaper_prints_button.grid(row= 3, column= 1, pady= 10)

final_frame = tk.LabelFrame(frame)
final_frame.grid(row=4, column=0)


name_label = tk.Label(final_frame)

ID_label = tk.Label(final_frame)
wl_label = tk.Label(final_frame)
ws_label = tk.Label(final_frame)
wp_label = tk.Label(final_frame)
extras_label = tk.Label(final_frame)
lining_paper_label = tk.Label(final_frame)
total_price_label = tk.Label(final_frame)




window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have failed to accurately reproduce the indentation of your code when you posted it here, which in the case of Python means that we can't tell what's in which function.  DON'T do any manual editing of the code - just paste it in, select it all, and hit the `{}` button on the editor toolbar to format it.

Comment: I would recommend to decouple your calculations entirely from the UI – that way you can test them in isolation, and then hook them up to the UI later.

Comment: The updated code does not produce the exception shown in the linked image.  Make sure you post the correct code and it is better a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get my tkinter prototype system calculate the correct total
> price

- On line 17, add `total_cost()` inside `enter_data()` function.
- On line 92, Use underscore `_total_cost =` because of duplicate `def total_cost():`

snippet:

```
def enter_data():
    total_cost() # Add this function
    ....
    ....
    ....
```

Screenshot:

[image]